# How to replace specific pattern words e.g ${pafta} from specifically in headers and front page in .doc/.docx files using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

`I am creating a Python program that loads a Word document and gets all words from it which follow this ${some_text} pattern and the program will replace those words from the document's paragraphs, tables, headers, footers, formatted text or you can say throughout the document.

Where did I stick?
I have attached my code below for a better understanding of my problem. When I run this code, it replaces those words from paragraphs and tables. But, It cannot replace headers, footers, and the front page of documents.

Also, I tried to read text from headers but whenever I print, it prints empty strings. If the program is not getting text from headers, front page, and footers then how will it modify them? Please help.

```
from docx import Document
def replace_text_in_docx(file_path, replacements):
doc = Document(file_path)
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        for old_text, new_text in replacements.items():
        if old_text in paragraph.text:
            if new_text.strip() != "":
                 paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(old_text, new_text)

    for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for old_text, new_text in replacements.items():
                    if old_text in cell.text:
                        cell.text = cell.text.replace(old_text, new_text)
    [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3GHz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NErhd.png)
    for section in doc.sections:
        if section.start_type == 1:  # Front formatted page
            for paragraph in section.header.paragraphs:
                for old_text, new_text in replacements.items():
                    if old_text in paragraph.text:
                        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(old_text, new_text)
    
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith("Heading"):
            for old_text, new_text in replacements.items():
                if old_text in paragraph.text:
                    runs = paragraph.runs
                    for run in runs:
                        if old_text in run.text:
                            updated_text = run.text.replace(old_text, new_text)
                            run.text = updated_text
    
        
    doc.save(file_path)`
```